# QGIS v3 Default CRS For New Projects settings not available, cannot enable OTF

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I would like to be able to enable on the fly transformation in version 3, I have followed the user guide instructions but I seem to be missing the options in the 'Options' window to allow this.
In the version 3 user guide the following instructions are given to enable the 'enable on the fly transformation' to be seen in the Project CRS window. This screenshot shows the image of the 'Options' window in the user guide.[image: image taken from user guide showing the options window]

> here are three ways to enable On The Fly CRS Transformation:
>
> > Select Project Properties ‣ CRS from the Project ( or Settings) menu. You can then activate the checkbox Enable on the fly CRS transformation (OTF) checkbox in the CRS tab and select the CRS to use (see Coordinate Reference System Selector)
> >
> > Click on the geographic CRS status icon in the lower right-hand corner of the status bar, leading you to the previous dialog.
> >
> > Turn OTF on by default in the CRS tab of the **Settings ‣ Options** dialog by selecting **checkbox Enable ‘on the fly’ reprojection by default or Automatically enable ‘on the fly’ reprojection if layers have different CRS**.

However, when I got to Settings, Options, CRS these options are missing (see screenshot)[image: my options, CRS available]. How can I activate them please?

Answer (score 2):

**Automatically enable 'on-the-fly'** has been made the default behavior in QGIS3. The documentation of this change has probably not been updated yet. Documentation focuses on Long-term release (LTR) versions and QGIS 3.0 is not LTR. The next LTR will be 3.4 (scheduled for Oct 2018).

Comment: Great, that explains the discrepancy, is there any way to disable 'on-the-fly'? Thanks

Comment: You can deactivate it in the project properties, but not by default.